# VB.NET: ListView Checkbox ALWAYS in first column

Tags: .net, listview, checkbox

I have a listview with checkbox property set to true, and I also allow column reordering. The problem is that when someone moves the first column to some other position, the checkboxes remain in that column and move with it to the new position - so eg. they can be in the middle of the listview.

I would like to have the checkboxes ALWAYS displayed in the first column. How can I do that? How do I refresh the listview to move the checkboxes again to the first column?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot to illustrate your point?

Comment: Sure. Here goes: http://www.imageno.com/pb0fkkqgapkmpic.html